# Is there a module similar to beautifulsoup in Blender?

Tags: python

I would like to convert an html string that I am currently obtaining from an webpage.
I currently get the whole page using the `requests` module (Present in Blender)

```
import requests
r = requests.get(url)
text=r.text
```

I would like to avoid using modules that are not present in Blender like `bs4`, but I don't know if this is possible.
Basically I would like to understand if there is something available in Blender's module library that facilitates the conversion to conventional text, or a trick that can do this.

**News:**

I found the module in Blender which seems to be useful for text files formatted in HTML

https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/html.parser.html

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser
```

Comment: IMO would go with the 3rd party module. To clarify blender includes a bare bones standard python install (+numpy...) and its API modules bpy, bpy_extras, bmesh etc. Web scraping is not blender related.  Building a web scraping module from the basic python tools, is in the end what the 3rd party module is. Suggest this is off-topic and recommend asking on a python related site.

Comment: @batFINGER Thanks, i don't have the ability to judge this, I trust in the community.
Although I think the question is related to blender, in the sense that I was specifically asking if there was a module available / distributed in blender. Thanks for the note